# Generating a list of numbers based on values in two columns in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

The kind of data we have is

```
From    To
1       5
6       10
```

Now, the result should be like-

```
Series
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I have achieved this result using Cursor but just curious to know if this can be achieved by using any other method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this in two ways.

Use a `Recursive CTE` to generate Numbers between `minimum` and `maximum` value in your table

```
CREATE TABLE #test([From] INT,[To]   INT)

INSERT #test
VALUES (1,5),(6,10) 

DECLARE @max INT

SELECT @max = Max([To])
FROM   #test;

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Min([From]) Series
         FROM   #test
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Series + 1
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  Series < @max)
SELECT Series
FROM   cte a
       JOIN #test b
         ON a.Series BETWEEN b.[From] AND b.[To]
```

Or use `Master..spt_values` to get the numbers

```
SELECT number As Series
FROM   master..spt_values a
       JOIN #test b
         ON a.number BETWEEN b.[From] AND b.[To]
WHERE  type = 'p'
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
+------+
|Series|
+------+
|1     |
|2     |
|3     |
|4     |
|5     |
|6     |
|7     |
|8     |
|9     |
|10    |
+------+
```

Comment: Can you please explain what master..spt_values is?

Comment: @kamalpreet It is a table present in `Master Database`. It has series of number stored in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #tempnumber (num INT)
INSERT INTO #tempnumber
SELECT t.[to] FROM yourtable t
UNION
SELECT t1.[from] FROM yourtable t1


DECLARE @max INT, @min INT
SELECT @max = MAX(num) FROM #tempnumber
SELECT @min = MIN(num) FROM #tempnumber

;WITH Series(a) AS
(
 SELECT (SELECT @min)
 UNION ALL
 SELECT a+1 FROM Series WHERE a < (SELECT @max)
)
SELECT * FROM Series;
```